# Extracting values from a file

Tags: arrays, perl

hope, somebody can help me with the following issue:

I have two lists of the following (either one tab-delimited):

chr\t start\t end\t alt\t ref\t .... (additional colums)

My goal is to compare both lists using a perl script on the basis of values in colums "start", "end", "alt" and "ref". That means, if values of a line in list 1 in these four colums equal entries in a line of list 2, the whole line of list 1 should be written to a file "common.txt". For the basic script I started to write content of list 1 into an array:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @file1;
open (FILE, "< path_to_file") || die "Can not find file: $!\n";
while (defined(my $i = <FILE>) {
     push (@file1, $i)
     }
print "@file1\n"; #temporary added line to test for output
```

As a result, an array @file1 is created containing all entries of FILE (thats fine, the array contains the values of FILE). The question now is: how do I specify the above mentioned colums. I tried to write the array into a scalar $content and wanted to isolate the second colum (start) using

```
$content = @file1;
print "$content[1]\n";
```

But (makes sense for sure), these lines give me the element [1] of the array that is the second line of FILE. 
Taken together: I wrote contents of FILE into array @file1 line by line using the while-loop. How can I extract the values of the defined colums? (Remark: the values of the specified colums are not known, so no use for pattern search).

Best,
Grumpy

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way to do parallel iteration of two files:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $INFILE1, '<', 'data1.txt';
open my $INFILE2, '<', 'data2.txt';
open my $OUTFILE, '>', 'common.txt';

while (!eof($INFILE1) and !eof($INFILE2)) {
    my $line1 = <$INFILE1>;
    my $line2 = <$INFILE2>;

    my(undef, $target1) = split ' ', $line1, 2;
    my(undef, $target2) = split ' ', $line2, 2;

    if ($target1 eq $target2) {
        print {$OUTFILE} $line1 
    }
}

close $INFILE1;
close $INFILE2;
close $OUTFILE;
```

---

Don't use *bareword* file handles, e.g.  File.  Instead, use `my` 
variables:

```
open my $FILE, '<', 'data.txt'
```

When you read from a file *in a while loop conditional*:

```
while (my $line = <$FILE>)
```

perl automatically does a `defined()` check on `$line`, and the while loop will only end when there are no more lines to read and `<>` returns `undef`.

Don't try to learn perl by reading old perl tutorials.  Instead, buy the latest edition of "Learning Perl" (Schwartz, d Foy, Phoenix).  Perl has the best books of any programming language that I've studied, so take advantage of that resource.  "Learning Perl" is fairly thin, as far as programming books go, so it won't take you a year to read through it all.  And, it has exercises at the end of every chapter with answers at the end of the book.

data1.txt:

```
a 1 2 3 4
b 5 6 7 8
c 3 4 5 5
d 2 2 2 2
```

data2.txt:

```
w 2 4 2 4
x 5 6 7 8
y 3 4 5 6
z 2 2 2 2
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $INFILE1, '<', 'data1.txt';
open my $INFILE2, '<', 'data2.txt';
open my $OUTFILE, '>', 'common.txt';

LINE_FROM_FILE1:
while (my $line1 = <$INFILE1>) {
    if (defined(my $line2 = <$INFILE2>)) {
        my($first1, $target1) = split ' ', $line1, 2;
        my($first2, $target2) = split ' ', $line2, 2;

        if ($target1 eq $target2) {
            print {$OUTFILE} $line1 
        }
    }
    else {
        say "File2 is shorter than File1.  " .
            "No more lines in File2...quitting";
        last;
    }
}

close $INFILE1;
close $INFILE2;
close $OUTFILE;
```

Output:

```
$ rm common.txt
remove common.txt? y

$ perl 1.pl 

$ cat common.txt
b 5 6 7 8
d 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: The code you provided works well after adjusting it! And as a perl newby the literature you indicated will be a great input.

Comment: @Grumpy, See the improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `split` to access the fields of each line:

```
for my $line (@file1) {
    my @fields = split "\t", $line;  # split into fields with TAB as a delimiter
    print "$fields[1]\n";            # print second field of each line
}
```

[split](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) and [join](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) should quickly become a natural part of your perl vocabulary if you're working with delimited files like this a lot.

Comment: *when the PATTERN is ... a
            literal string composed of a single space character...the
            PATTERN is instead treated as if it were "/\s+/"* -- CSV files are notoriously corrupted by spaces instead of tabs or spaces and tabs, so you could end up comparing two strings where one string has a leading or trailing space.  On the other hand, if column 1 contains multiple "words", then you would need to split on tabs only.

Comment: I have already used split, but made a mess with the fields. Your input helped a lot!!